# when validate bootstrap input controls getting shrinked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am running one bootstrap application where i am using input textbox. when i am using validation for the textbox it is getting shrinked.

Code is below:

```html
 $("#formConfPass").addClass("has-error has-feedback").removeClass("control-group");
```

so using this code input control showing in red border but it's state is changed. how to make control stable?

Comment: Can you elaborate this using codepen or fiddle?

Comment: I have uploaded the image of login page before validate and after validate. Below is the link to compare both 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/gfvkx5 Please check this issue and give me goog suggestion.